# sys.excepthook not returning exceptions

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to log unhandled exceptions except I can't seem to get "sys.excepthook" to function properly. The code seems to run without error yet it just doesn't do anything. Thanks.

I've tried logging it to file, realized that my logging code does work so switched it to different code just to see if i could test sys.excepthook.

```py
import sys

def handleException(excType, value, traceback):
    print('work plz')

sys.excepthook = handleException
raise RuntimeError("Test unhandled")
```

or

```py
import sys

def handleException(excType, value, traceback):
    print('work plz')

sys.excepthook = handleException
c = "a" + 2
```

returns

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/x/Desktop/python/marketing/3/log_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Test unhandled")
RuntimeError: Test unhandled
```

I'm expecting there to be "work plz"

EDIT: It seems to be an issue with IDLE, if i run the program directly and try to log to file it works, yet if I try to run it through IDLE it doesn't. It's odd, but I guess fixed.

Answer (score 0):

IPython does not support the `sys.excepthook` way to intercept the exceptions. Maybe you can have a try of the way like below.

```py
class ExceptionHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def __call__(self, *exception_info):
        """Handles exceptions"""
        ...

    def as_ipython_handler(self):
        def handle_ipython(shell, exception_type, value, tb, tb_offset=None):
            # shell.showtraceback((exception_type, value, tb), tb_offset=tb_offset)
            self(exception_type, value, tb)
            return traceback.format_tb(tb)

        return handle_ipython



try:
    # print("ipython_shell")
    ipython_shell = get_ipython() # only work on ipython
    ipython_shell.set_custom_exc((Exception,), ExceptionHandler().as_ipython_handler())
except NameError as e:
    # print("console")
    sys.excepthook = ExceptionHandler()
```